# How to get a count of list items from Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm using below code to travers my list it is working fine if List Items are visible.

If List is scrollable then non visible items are not accessing using this code. How to traverse all the list items which are visble + non visible items.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.getCount;i++)
{
   View v = list.getChildAt(i);
   TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
   Log.d("","ListItem :"+tv.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently i did this thing.
Suppose i want to invisible a button on a listItem. Then in the getView of the list adapter add that button in a global vector. like below.

```
 Button del_btn = viewCache.getFrame();
 view_vec.add(del_btn);
```

Here viewCache is a object of ViewCache class, which is sumthing like below -

```
   class ViewCache 
     {        

         private View baseView;     
         private Button button;


         public ViewCache(View baseView) 
         {       
             this.baseView = baseView;   
         }  

         public Button getButton() {
             if(button == null) {
                 button = (Button)   baseView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteChatFrndBtn);
             }
             return button;
         }
     }  


 //it is necessary sometimes because otherwise in some cases the list scroll is slow.
```

Now you like to visible the listItem's button onClicking some other button. Then the code is like below -

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.EditChatFrndBtn:
            length = view_vec.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                Button btn = (Button) view_vec.elementAt(i);
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            doneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
     }
}
```

Instead of R.id.EditChatFrndBtn put your button id on clicking of which you will invisible/visible the listItem's button.

Comment: Hi, I need show buttons on every list item on click of another button, which is in my header. Can you please explain what is this view vector that you used and what getFrame() does?

Comment: See you have to keep track of all buttons(views) at the time of its creation. Otw after that you cant access each list item button view separately.So when every button view is created i insert it in a view vector.This vector will keep track of all list item button view.

Comment: Got it, and Viewcache is the holder for view in adapter. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can get your ListView in the Activity and traverse it.

```
ListView myList = getListView();
int count = myList.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
   ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) myList.getChildAt(i);
   TextView tvTest = (TextView) row.findviewbyid(R.id.tvTestID);
    //  Get your controls from this ViewGroup and perform your task on them =)

}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: can you explain me, what is the difference to get list childs from View or ViewGroup?